# Check Uses Network Location and Alert

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a very simple need. I want to check if the user has enabled the use network location checkbox. If it is enabled, I want to pass the user to an activity called LOCATIONPAGE. If network location is not enabled, I want to display an alert.

This sounds very simple but I am going absolutely crazy trying to figure this out. Everything seems to work find if I remove the check and pass the user directly to the LOCATIONPAGE activity. Any ideas would be very helpful. Thank you!

```
package com.appname.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gpsoff);


        Thread logoTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try{
                    int logoTimer = 0;
                    while (logoTimer<6000){
                        sleep(100);
                        logoTimer = logoTimer+100;
                    }

                    LocationManager locManager =  (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    boolean networkEnabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    if(!networkEnabled){


                        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
                        alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Message");
                        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                              // TODO Add your code for the button here.
                           }
                        });
                        // Set the Icon for the Dialog
                        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                        alertDialog.show();
                        // see http://www.androidsnippets.com/simple-alert-dialog-popup-with-title-message-icon-and-button

                    }

                    else {

                    startActivity(new Intent("com.appname.app.LOCATIONPAGE"));

                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally{
                    finish();
                }
            }

            private LocationManager getSystemService(String locationService) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

        };
        logoTimer.start();




    }

}
```

Comment: Your moto didn't clear, what you want to do ?

Comment: your activity is not started as finish() is called.

Comment: thanks @ShaniGoriwal, why is finish() called when I do not have an if statement. For example, if I remove the networkEnabled if statement, and just leave the startActivity, then it works just fine... how should i restructure this so finish() does not get called?

Comment: gr8, so tell me ur problem is solved or not???

Comment: @ShaniGoriwal - it is not solved yet. I need to restructure the code so that I can use the if statement. I just don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm getting you correctly this what you need.

I am here using shared Preferences to fulfill the check box need;

by the following code:

```
 prefs.xml

    <CheckBoxPreference
      android:defaultValue="true"
      android:key="alpha"
      android:summary="Check/Uncheck"
      android:title="Location" />
```

Now inflate the same prefs.xml in PrefsActivity

Now in Main Activity:

```
      SharedPreferences sp =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
      Boolean result = sp.getBoolean("alpha", true);
      if (result)
       {
       if(checkNetwrok())
        {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, LocationPage.class)
                startActivity(i);
        {  
        else 
        {
                Show toast/Dialog with "network not found !"
        }   
       }
  else {
           msg: pls enable the network checkbox first
       }

    public boolean checkNetwork(){
          LocationManager locManager =  (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
          boolean networkEnabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        return networkEnabled;
     }
```